# Querying rows from multiple tables

Tags: mysql, distinct, duplicates

I'm trying to make a  query form two different tables which are not related anyhow.
This is my MySQL query: `select ideas.idea_id,ask.ask_id from ideas,ask;`
I expect to get just 8 rows in each column but it returns me 64 rows duplicating each row 8 times

```
+---------+--------+
| idea_id | ask_id |
+---------+--------+
|      69 |      1 |
|      69 |      2 |
|      69 |      3 |
|      69 |      4 |
|      69 |      5 |
|      69 |      6 |
|      69 |      7 |
|      69 |      8 |
|      70 |      1 |
|      70 |      2 |
|      70 |      3 |
|      70 |      4 |
|      70 |      5 |
|      70 |      6 |
|      70 |      7 |
|      70 |      8 |
|      71 |      1 |
|      71 |      2 |
|      71 |      3 |
|      71 |      4 |
|      71 |      5 |
|      71 |      6 |
|      71 |      7 |
|      71 |      8 |
|      72 |      1 |
|      72 |      2 |
|      72 |      3 |
|      72 |      4 |
|      72 |      5 |
|      72 |      6 |
|      72 |      7 |
|      72 |      8 |
|      73 |      1 |
|      73 |      2 |
|      73 |      3 |
|      73 |      4 |
|      73 |      5 |
|      73 |      6 |
|      73 |      7 |
|      73 |      8 |
|      74 |      1 |
|      74 |      2 |
|      74 |      3 |
|      74 |      4 |
|      74 |      5 |
|      74 |      6 |
|      74 |      7 |
|      74 |      8 |
|      75 |      1 |
|      75 |      2 |
|      75 |      3 |
|      75 |      4 |
|      75 |      5 |
|      75 |      6 |
|      75 |      7 |
|      75 |      8 |
|      76 |      1 |
|      76 |      2 |
|      76 |      3 |
|      76 |      4 |
|      76 |      5 |
|      76 |      6 |
|      76 |      7 |
|      76 |      8 |
+---------+--------+
```

I've tried to use distinct by it doesn't do anything.

If you could help me it would be great.
Thanks

Comment: How exactly are you expecting to link the lines, if the tables are not related anyhow? If you select from two tables, it returns cartesian product, i.e. each line from one table combined with each line from other table. If you have a look into your result, none of the lines are actually duplicated, each is different.

Comment: Can u post your query here?

Comment: Thanks Tomas, now it makes sense for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now you get cross join every field from first table connects to the second 8х8=64
You need a join field  add a field to both tables with the same unique values and join by it

Answer (score 0):

Try using outer join on id fields from 2 tables... so that though rows doesn't match you get all results